# Used Firefox Add-on Builder and the extension doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Thought i would try to build and extension for firefox so I used the Add-on Builder to build a basic extension at MDC. When I click the extension in the Tools menu it is ment to bring up a hello world popup, but it doesn't.

I think its the onLoad function fails to fetch the data from nigol-strings. But if its a generated code from the MDC website why does it have errors or is it me?

```
var nigol = {
  onLoad: function() {
    // initialization code
    this.initialized = true;
    this.strings = document.getElementById("nigol-strings");
  },

  onMenuItemCommand: function(e) {
    var promptService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"]
                                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPromptService);
    promptService.alert(window, this.strings.getString("helloMessageTitle"),
                                this.strings.getString("helloMessage"));
  }
};

window.addEventListener("load", nigol.onLoad, false);
```

Like i said I downloaded from the addon builder and have not made any alterations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you're calling `onLoad`, the value of `this` in that function is not what you think it is. Try this instead:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { nigol.onLoad(); }, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay MatrixFrog but that had no results. I get what your saying about this.strings only being set in the onLoad function. So how would i make it so all functions could call upon it? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're having the same problem with `onMenuItemCommand`. Check the docs, I think the value of `this` in that function might be the target of the event. Just do `nigol.strings.getString` and I suspect it will work okay.